# QDialog with QScrollArea adjustSize on widget hide

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

**File: search.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '/home/chris/Documents/papinhio-player/ui/menu-3/radio-stations/search/search.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(837, 556)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/main-window/assets/images/main-window/search.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea{\n"
"    border:0px;\n"
"}")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Dialog)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 837, 556))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.search_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.search_frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}")
        self.search_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.search_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.search_frame.setObjectName("search_frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.search_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.search_phrase = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.search_frame)
        self.search_phrase.setObjectName("search_phrase")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.search_phrase)
        self.search_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.search_frame)
        self.search_button.setIcon(icon)
        self.search_button.setObjectName("search_button")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.search_button)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.search_frame)
        self.loading_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.loading_frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"}")
        self.loading_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.loading_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.loading_frame.setObjectName("loading_frame")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.loading_frame)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(291, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.loading_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.loading_frame)
        self.loading_label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(220, 20))
        self.loading_label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(220, 20))
        self.loading_label.setText("")
        self.loading_label.setObjectName("loading_label")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.loading_label)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(290, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.loading_frame)
        self.results_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.results_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"    font-weight:bold;\n"
"    text-decoration:underline;\n"
"}")
        self.results_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.results_label.setObjectName("results_label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.results_label)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.table.setObjectName("table")
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"    font-weight:bold;\n"
"    color:green;\n"
"}")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/ok.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.ok.setIcon(icon1)
        self.ok.setObjectName("ok")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ok)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Εύρεση ραδιοφωνικών συνδέσεων"))
        self.search_phrase.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Dialog", "Αναζήτηση βάση τίτλου ραδιοφωνικής σύνδεσης"))
        self.search_button.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Αναζήτηση"))
        self.results_label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Αποτέλεσμα αναζήτησης: Η αναζήτηση ολοκληρώθηκε επιτυχώς. Βρέθηκαν ... ραδιοφωνικές συνδέσεις"))
        item = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Τίτλος"))
        item = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Radio hostname"))
        item = self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ενέργεια"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Σημείωση 1: Η αναζήτηση πραγματοποιείτε με κριτήριο τον τίτλο των ραδιοφωνικών συνδέσεων.\n"
"Σημείωση 2: Αφήστε κένο πεδίο για εύρεση όλων των ραδιοφωνικών συνδέσεων.\n"
"Σημείωση 3: Η αναζήτηση είναι case insensitive δηλαδή θα πρέπει να δοκιμάσετε και με κεφαλαίους χαρακτήρες εφόσον δεν βρεθούν αποτελέσματα."))
        self.ok.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Εντάξει - Κλείσιμο παραθύρου"))
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../')

#import importlib
#icons = importlib.import_module('compiled-ui.icons')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

File: **search_support.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import search
import sys

class Run_me:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = search.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)
        self.Dialog.show()
        
        
        self.ui.table.setColumnWidth(0, 350)
        self.ui.table.setColumnWidth(1, 120)
        

        
        self.ui.loading_frame.hide()
        self.ui.table.hide()
        self.ui.results_label.hide()
        
        self.Dialog.adjustSize()
        
        
        self.Dialog.hide()
        self.Dialog.show()
        self.Dialog.update()
        


        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    programm = Run_me()
```

Try to run search_support.py

The result is:

[image]

but the desired result is:

[image]

How can i adjustSize of QDialog which has inside a QScrollArea?
Which size policies should i use?

Here is the search.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>837</width>
    <height>556</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Εύρεση ραδιοφωνικών συνδέσεων</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>:/main-window/assets/images/main-window/search.png</normaloff>:/main-window/assets/images/main-window/search.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QScrollArea{
    border:0px;
}</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <property name="leftMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="topMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="rightMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <property name="bottomMargin">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>837</width>
        <height>556</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="search_frame">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QFrame{
    border:none;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLineEdit" name="search_phrase">
            <property name="placeholderText">
             <string>Αναζήτηση βάση τίτλου ραδιοφωνικής σύνδεσης</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="search_button">
            <property name="text">
             <string>Αναζήτηση</string>
            </property>
            <property name="icon">
             <iconset>
              <normaloff>:/main-window/assets/images/main-window/search.png</normaloff>:/main-window/assets/images/main-window/search.png</iconset>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="loading_frame">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QFrame{
    border:none;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>291</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
          <item>
           <widget class="QLabel" name="loading_label">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>220</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>220</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string/>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
          <item>
           <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
            <property name="orientation">
             <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
             <size>
              <width>290</width>
              <height>20</height>
             </size>
            </property>
           </spacer>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="results_label">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Αποτέλεσμα αναζήτησης: Η αναζήτηση ολοκληρώθηκε επιτυχώς. Βρέθηκαν ... ραδιοφωνικές συνδέσεις</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTableWidget" name="table">
         <attribute name="horizontalHeaderCascadingSectionResizes">
          <bool>false</bool>
         </attribute>
         <attribute name="horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize">
          <number>150</number>
         </attribute>
         <attribute name="horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </attribute>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Τίτλος</string>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Radio hostname</string>
          </property>
         </column>
         <column>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Ενέργεια</string>
          </property>
         </column>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QLabel{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:green;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Σημείωση 1: Η αναζήτηση πραγματοποιείτε με κριτήριο τον τίτλο των ραδιοφωνικών συνδέσεων.
Σημείωση 2: Αφήστε κένο πεδίο για εύρεση όλων των ραδιοφωνικών συνδέσεων.
Σημείωση 3: Η αναζήτηση είναι case insensitive δηλαδή θα πρέπει να δοκιμάσετε και με κεφαλαίους χαρακτήρες εφόσον δεν βρεθούν αποτελέσματα.</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignJustify|Qt::AlignVCenter</set>
         </property>
         <property name="wordWrap">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="ok">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Εντάξει - Κλείσιμο παραθύρου</string>
         </property>
         <property name="icon">
          <iconset>
           <normaloff>:/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/ok.png</normaloff>:/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/ok.png</iconset>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

1. QDialog:

Horizontal policy: preferred

Vertical policy: preferred

2. QScrollArea:

Horizontal policy: Expanding

Vertical policy: Expanding

3. scrollAreaWidgetContents:

Horizontal policy: **Ignored**

Vertical policy: **Fixed**

4. After that i tried the following code:

```py
        q_dialog_width = self.Dialog.width()
        
        self.Dialog.adjustSize()
        self.Dialog.hide()
        self.Dialog.show()        
        
        self.Dialog.adjustSize()
        search_frame_height = self.ui.search_frame.height()
        label_2_height = self.ui.label_2.height()
        ok_height = self.ui.ok.height()
        q_dialog_height = 11 + search_frame_height + 11 + label_2_height + 11 +ok_height + 11 - 8 #I don't know why - 8 is neccessary        
        self.Dialog.setGeometry(50,50,q_dialog_width,q_dialog_height)
```

And that's it. The QDialog height it's adjusted to it's contents.

Print Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QScrollArea caches the size hint of the child widget when `sizeHint()` is called the first time, so you can use a promoted widget for the main scroll area and re-implement it so that it always returns the current size hint.

```
class ScrollArea(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.widget() is not None:
            f = self.frameWidth() * 2
            return self.widget().sizeHint() + QtCore.QSize(f, f)
        return super().sizeHint()
```